# remove 1 index value after each iteration

Tags: python, list

I have a list of values, want to extract the first 3 values every time, and need to remove 1st index position value after iteration.

```
a = [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]
```

Output:

```
[[11,12,13],[12,13,14],[13,14,15],[14,15,16],[15,16,17],[16,17,18],[17,18,19]]
```

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension is probably fairly straightforward to understand-

```
a = [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]
a_out = [a[i:i+3] for i in range(len(a)-2)]
```

Or you can cut and piece together portions of the list with `zip` too, if this approach makes more sense -

```
a_out = list(zip(a[0:-2], a[1:-1], a[2:]))
```